# PHP script works online but no offline

Tags: php

This script works online but not offline via WAMP...

```
function current_user()
    {
        static $current_user;
        if(!$current_user)
        {
            if($_SESSION['userID'])
            {
                $userID = intval($_SESSION['userID']);
                $query = "SELECT * 
                          FROM `users`
                          WHERE `id` = $userID";
                $data  = mysql_query($query);
                if(mysql_num_rows($data))
                {
                    $current_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
                    return $current_user;
                }
            }
        }
        return $current_user;
    }
```

When this function is called, I get the following error message...

```
Notice: Undefined index: userID in C:\wamp\www\alpha\_includes\session.php on line 38
```

Line 38 is `$userID = intval($_SESSION['userID']);`

The error only occurs when the `userID` SESSION variable isn't set. That and when the function is called via a page from my offline testing computer (running WAMP).

---

As a side note, this isn't my script. Credit goes to Jim Hoskins of Think Vitamin Membership.

Comment: Correction to the title.... PHP script works online but NOT offline.

Comment: Rename `$userID` to `$somethingwhichisnotasessionkey`, any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have notices enabled on one server, but not the other. This notice is just telling you that are attempting to read an array element that doesn't exist.

Instead, try this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userID']))
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized that just seconds before you posted your answer when stillstanding posted his answer. I had error checking on. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

It's a notice, not an error. To fix:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userID']) && $_SESSION['userID'])
```

Comment: Thank you. I was asking why it shows offline but not online. You indirectly answer my question. I remember that my php.ini are different between online and offline.

Comment: I would love to give you the credit for helping. However, Paul has the correct answer. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

change `if($_SESSION['userID'])` to `if(isset($_SESSION['userID']))` first check whether the session variable 'userID' is set before we use it.

Try this code

```
function current_user()
    {
        static $current_user;
        if(!$current_user)
        {
            if($_SESSION['userID'])
            {
                $userID = intval($_SESSION['userID']);
                $query = "SELECT * 
                          FROM `users`
                          WHERE `id` = $userID";
                $data  = mysql_query($query);
                if(mysql_num_rows($data))
                {
                    $current_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
                    return $current_user;
                }
            }
        }
        return $current_user;
    }
```